# Execute methods following the order of a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project and want to call methods one after another using a predefined list.

In this test scenario I want to execute startTrialWithFixedValue1() two times, startTrialWithFixedValue2() two times and startTrialWithRandomValue() one time in the end. Every time the user makes an input, I want to execute the next method from the list. There are two major problems with my code:

(1) Whenever I use an if statement with return the variable countTrial becomes unreachable. The debug log shows always 0:1 and the first method is executed all the time.

(2) If I exclude the return statement, all methods are started at once.

[EDIT] To specify my question: How can I execute methods following the order of a given list.

Script A:

```
public int countTrial;
public int maxTrials = 16;
public Spawner spawner;

List<int> trialMarkers = new List<int>() {1, 1, 2, 2, 3};

public void chooseNextTrial()
{
    for (int countTrial = 0; countTrial < maxTrials; countTrial++)
    {
        Debug.Log(countTrial + ": " + trialMarkers[countTrial]);

        if (trialMarkers[countTrial] == 1)
        {
            spawner.startTrialWithFixedValue1();
            return;
        }
        if (trialMarkers[countTrial] == 2)
        {
            spawner.startTrialWithFixedValue2();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            spawner.startTrialWithRandomValue();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Script B:

```
public void handleUserInput()
{
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            deleteAllChildren();
            chooseTrial.chooseNextTrial();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me!

[EDIT2] As suggested by Programmer: Remove the return statement in that function then run it again. Copy and paste the result of Debug.Log(countTrial + ": " + trialMarkers[countTrial]); the result is always:

```
5:3
5:3
5:3
...
```

Comment: Title is misleading and there are no methods stored in the List. I also can't tell what your question is

Comment: Please describe carefully what your underlying problem is. Don't re-ask this question.

Comment: As previously stated, you are not calling a method in a list, take some time to understand what your for loop is actually doing, and what your code is actually doing.  The way you explain it in your question it appears you understand neither.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I edited the first post to specify my question.

Comment: You still aren't showing you truly understand whats going on with your for loop.  You are always starting with an index of 0 so your debug statement will always say `0:1`  You are never actually advancing in the list because of your return statement, if you want this done 1 at a time, and you have no use for previous attempts you might as well as remove the for loop, compare the first index in your list, and then remove it after you call your method.

Comment: Remove the `return` statement in that function then run it again. Copy and paste the result of `Debug.Log(countTrial + ": " + trialMarkers[countTrial]);` log in your question

Comment: Since you are returning the chooseNextTrial after every execution of method spawner.startTrialWithFixedValue you need to define the countTrial outside the scope of chooseNextTrial and change its value to ++ every time you want the process to start (eg. In the input IF statement) Otherwise it start from zero all over again when u call it.

Comment: Is there a reason you declare `public int countTrial;` and then create a local variable with the same name (`int countTrial`) in the `for` loop?

Comment: you could use a dictionnary of <string, delegate> and call your function with a string refering to a key of the dictionary. It would be more readable and not use conditions.

Comment: @Greg `countTrial` shouldn't be a problem since you can re-declare variable again in a local space.

Comment: @Programmer wow there is two Greg, and I receive his notification. Fortunately I did not choose Jon Skeet as username

Comment: Yes and that's funny. I took a screenshot to ask question about this on Meta but I spend one hour trying to reply to one of you.

Comment: @Programmer, correct.  It'll definitely work, just could cause confusion on the part of the programmer, especially if (s)he is using that variable in another method.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Greg No problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the For loop and handle the execution of Method more manualy

```
public int countTrial = 0;
public int maxTrials = 16;
public Spawner spawner;

List<int> trialMarkers = new List<int>() {1, 1, 2, 2, 3};

    public void chooseNextTrial()
    {

            Debug.Log(countTrial + ": " + trialMarkers[countTrial]);
            if (trialMarkers[countTrial] == 1)
            {
                spawner.startTrialWithFixedValue1();
            }
            if (trialMarkers[countTrial] == 2)
            {
                spawner.startTrialWithFixedValue2();
            }
            else
            {
                spawner.startTrialWithRandomValue();
            }
      }
```

And then inside your second script (Script B) which handles the user input

```
public void handleUserInput()
{
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            deleteAllChildren();
            chooseTrial.chooseNextTrial();
            chooseTrial.countTrial++;
        }
}
```

End line: You shouldnt use a Fop loop since you want the sequence to be startied whith a player input action and handle it like this. Also adding a method like this:

```
public void NextCounter()
{
     if(countTrial<trialMarkers.Count)
         countTrial++

}
```

In your Script A and then call it like this in Script B to avoid your counter going above the list count.

```
chooseTrial.NextCounter();
```

Insteed of using the countTrial++ in SCript B

Answer (score 1):

When you return in the method you are breaking out of your loop.

```
 for (int countTrial = 0; countTrial < (maxTrials <= trialMarkers.Count ? maxTrails : trialMarkers.Count) ; countTrial++)
 {
     Debug.Log(countTrial + ": " + trialMarkers[countTrial]);

     if (trialMarkers[countTrial] == 1)
     {
         spawner.startTrialWithFixedValue1();
     }
     if (trialMarkers[countTrial] == 2)
     {
         spawner.startTrialWithFixedValue2();
     }
     else
     {
         spawner.startTrialWithRandomValue();
     }
 }
```

Will execute the way you are asking.  Also note I changed your iterator so that you do not get an object reference error in your loop.

Comment: In  the question, OP already said he removed `return`  from the code....

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something similar to what you describe in the title (which gives the impression that you have a "list of functions").  This example is easily extensible:

```
 private Action[] _functions;

 public void MainEntryPoint()
 {
     _functions = new Action[] { StartTrialWithFixedValue1, StartTrialWithFixedValue2, StartTrialWithRandomValue };
     List<int> trialMarkers = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
     DoThings(trialMarkers);
 }

 public void DoThings(IEnumerable<int> indexesOfFuctions)
 {
     foreach (var index in indexesOfFuctions)
     {
         _functions[index-1]();
     }
 }

 private void StartTrialWithFixedValue1()
 {
     Trace.WriteLine("StartTrialWithFixedValue1");
 }

 private void StartTrialWithFixedValue2()
 {
     Trace.WriteLine("StartTrialWithFixedValue2");
 }

 private void StartTrialWithRandomValue()
 {
     Trace.WriteLine("StartTrialWithRandomValue");
 }
```

I create an "array of functions" (actually of Delegates to functions), and then I use your list of instructions to execute them.